# Customer Invoice

Tags: magento2, orders, invoice

I have a client that wants line numbers added to each item in an outfit invoice.

I cannot find any obvious ways to do this in the template files as the items are called in the `Magento_Sales::email/invoice/items.phtml`

Does the item or order collection store the key for that product regarding an order?

Comment: What do you mean by line numbers? What do you exactly want?

Comment: Bascially I need on the left of each item in the invoice an iterating number.
1  .  Item A .  SKU .  QTY  .  Price .  Subtotal
2  .  Item A .  SKU .  QTY  .  Price .  Subtotal

Comment: For Invoices in admin right?

Answer (score 1):

You can manage it by following steps also need to create your custom module:

**Step 1:**
Create file **sales_order_invoice_view.xml** under below path:

> app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_invoice_view.xml

Content will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="invoice_items" template="Vendor_Module::order/invoice/view/items.phtml">
            <referenceBlock name="invoice_items.default" template="Vendor_Module::order/invoice/view/items/renderer/default.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step 2:**
Create **items.phtml** under below path:

> app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/view/adminhtml/templates/order/invoice/view/items.phtml

Content will be:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<div class="admin__table-wrapper">
    <table class="data-table admin__table-primary order-invoice-tables">
        <thead>
            <tr class="headings">
                <th></th>
                <th class="col-product"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Product') ?></span></th>
                <th class="col-price"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Price') ?></span></th>
                <th class="col-qty"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span></th>
                <th class="col-subtotal"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Subtotal') ?></span></th>
                <th class="col-tax"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Tax Amount') ?></span></th>
                <th class="col-discount"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Discount Amount') ?></span></th>
                <th class="col-total last"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Row Total') ?></span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php $_items = $block->getInvoice()->getAllItems() ?>
        <?php $i = 0; foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
            <?php if ($_item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
            continue;
        } else {
            $i++;
        } ?>
            <tbody class="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $i%2 ? 'even' : 'odd' ?>">
                <tr>
                    <td><?= $i ?></td>
                    <?= $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                </tr>
                <?= $block->getItemExtraInfoHtml($_item->getOrderItem()) ?>
            </tbody>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Step 2:**
Create **default.phtml** under below path:

> app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/view/adminhtml/templates/order/invoice/view/items/renderer/default.phtml

Content will be:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php /** @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer */ ?>
<?php $_item = $block->getItem() ?>
<?php $_item->setStoreId($_item->getInvoice()->getStoreId()) ?>
<?php $block->setPriceDataObject($_item) ?>
<td class="col-product"><?= $block->getColumnHtml($_item, 'name') ?></td>
<td class="col-price">
    <?= $block->getColumnHtml($_item, 'price') ?>
</td>
<td class="col-qty"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getQty()*1 ?></td>
<td class="col-subtotal">
    <?= $block->getColumnHtml($_item, 'subtotal') ?>
</td>
<td class="col-tax"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->displayPriceAttribute('tax_amount') ?></td>
<td class="col-discount"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->displayPriceAttribute('discount_amount') ?></td>
<td class="col-total last">
    <?= $block->getColumnHtml($_item, 'total') ?>
</td>
```

Hope this helps!